# .HTaccess Removing spaces from hashtag redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Can anyone assist I have this rule

```
RewriteRule ^hashtag/([^\/]+)(\/|)$ index.php?link1=hashtag&hash=$1 [NC,B,BNP,QSA]
```

I want to remove space from url `https://Domain.co.uk/hashtag/ Automotive Filters Market trends` rewritten to `https://Domain.co.uk/hashtag/AutomotiveFiltersMarkettrends`.

Any help much appriciated as I can't fathom it out myself.

Not tried anything yet as everything I did crashed the site. I don't know what I am doing with that ".htaccess" style file.